# Update a document by removing an element from an array of object field based on field of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents

```
[
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: [
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc1",
          CBB: "abcd",
          CBC: "ancdf",
        },
      },
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc2",
          CBB: "abcd1",
          CBC: "ancdf2",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: [
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc3",
          CBB: "abcd3",
          CBC: "ancdf3",
        },
      },
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc2",
          CBB: "abcd1",
          CBC: "ancdf2",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: [
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc4",
          CBB: "abcd4",
          CBC: "ancdf4",
        },
      },
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc24",
          CBB: "abcd5",
          CBC: "ancd6",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: [
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc1",
          CBB: "abcd",
          CBC: "ancdf",
        },
      },
      {
        cA1: "CA1",
        CB1: {
          CBA: "abc2",
          CBB: "abcd1",
          CBC: "ancdf2",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

What I want to do is to delete the elements from field **c** in the matched documents depending on field values of **CB1** object.

What I have done is

```
const x = db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  {
    $pull: {
      c: {
        $elemMatch: {
            CB1: {
            $in: [
              {
                CBA: "abc2",
                CBB: "abcd1",
              },
              {
                CBA: "abc1",
                CBB: "abcd",
              }
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  { multi: true }
);
```

Its not working. What is want to do is remove all elements from **c** where **CB1** has fields with the value mentioned in **$in** array. If its truly not possible to use **$in** on that level deleting one by one will also work.

Comment: What is the expected output? If `CB1` has both options than delete all items in `c`?

Comment: @nimrodserok yes

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
db.collection.update(
  {c: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $or: [
        {"CB1.CBA": "abc2", "CB1.CBB": "abcd1"},
        {"CB1.CBA": "abc1", "CB1.CBB": "abcd"}
      ]
    }
  }},
  [
    {$set: {
      delete: {$size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$c",
            cond: {
              $or: [
                {$and: [
                    {$eq: ["$$this.CB1.CBA", "abc1"]},
                    {$eq: ["$$this.CB1.CBB", "abcd"]}
                ]},
                {$and: [
                    {$eq: ["$$this.CB1.CBA", "abc2"]},
                    {$eq: ["$$this.CB1.CBB", "abcd1"]}
                ]}
              ]
            }
          }
      }}
    }},
    {$set: {c: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$delete", 2]}, [], "$c"]}, delete: "$$REMOVE"}}
  ],
  {multi: true}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_bL_LZySw8G)